# Jquery take a price from a span and i want to make it static

Tags: jquery, static, field, html, creation

i make this function :

```
function price(val){
var test = $('span.hikashop_product_price_full:visible').text();
var test2 = test.split('%');
var test3 = test2[1].split(' ');
var test4 = test3[0].replace(',','.');
var eyy = parseFloat(test4) *val/100 + parseFloat(test4);
eyy = eyy.toFixed(2)
var ett = test.replace(test3[0]+' '+test3[1],'<span class=\"hikashop_product_price hikashop_product_price_0 hikashop_product_price_with_discount\">'+eyy+' '+test3[1]+'</span>');
$('span.hikashop_product_price_full:visible').html(ett);

}
```

i take a value from a dynamic `<span>` tag (say it is dynamic because it changes depending on other field).
i have a field

```
<select id="custome_vara" name="data[item][custome_vara]" size="1" onchange="price(this.value);">
<option value="" id="custome_vara_" selected="selected">alb</option>
<option value="20" id="custome_vara_20">stejar auriu</option>
<option value="30" id="custome_vara_30">moreiche</option>
</select>
```

and it trigger every time i call it. I need to run just once to add `%` to the initial price.

the span looks like this

```
<span class="hikashop_product_discount">-10%</span><span class="hikashop_product_price hikashop_product_price_0 hikashop_product_price_with_discount">51,34 €</span> </span>
```

Question:

When I call the function price() it run the selection on this function and make the selection a int. 
How to make the selection static and the field select/option add to this static selection a percent just once per option.

I hope u understood.

Sorry for my english.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are missing something that we need to see:  `span.hikashop_product_price_full` - what is that?

Comment: span.hikashop_product_price_full is <span class="hikashop_product_price_full" id="hikashop_product_price_full"> <span class="hikashop_product_discount">-10%</span><span class="hikashop_product_price hikashop_product_price_0 hikashop_product_price_with_discount">51,34 €</span> </span> </span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<select id="custome_vara" name="data[item][custome_vara]" size="1" onchange="price(this.value);">
```

to

```
<select id="custome_vara" name="data[item][custome_vara]" size="1">
```

then add this:

```
$('#custome_vara').one('change',function(){
    price($(this+'option:selected').val());
});
```

EDIT: In hopes of making your intent clear I will post some "errors" here:

First, you are missing markup example of:

```
'span.hikashop_product_price_full:visible'
```

Second:

```
eyy = eyy.toFixed(2)
```

should be:

```
eyy = eyy.toFixed(2);
```

Third:

```
'<span class=\"hikashop_product_price hikashop_product_price_0 hikashop_product_price_with_discount\">'
```

can be written as:

```
'<span class="hikashop_product_price hikashop_product_price_0 hikashop_product_price_with_discount">'
```

I created this fiddle page to help us understand each other:  http://jsfiddle.net/2fxxD/

EDIT2:
I think I see what you want.  See the following in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/2fxxD/3/

```
function priceNew(val) {
    var discountedPrice = $('.hikashop_product_price_with_discount');
    var percentOff = $('.hikashop_product_discount');
    var price = discountedPrice.text().split(' ');
    var decimalPrice = price[0].replace(',', '.');
    var eyy = parseFloat(decimalPrice) * val / 100 + parseFloat(decimalPrice);
    eyy = eyy.toFixed(2);
    var newPrice = eyy + ' ' + price[1];
    discountedPrice.text(newPrice);
    percentOff.text('-' + val + '%');
    $('.hikashop_product_price').text(newPrice);
}

$('#custome_vara').one('change', function() {
    priceNew($(this + 'option:selected').val());
});
```

Markup:

```
<select id="custome_vara" name="data[item][custome_vara]" size="1">
    <option value="" id="custome_vara_" selected="selected">alb</option> 
    <option value="20" id="custome_vara_20">stejar auriu</option>
    <option value="30" id="custome_vara_30">moreiche</option>
</select>
<div>
<span class="hikashop_product_price_full" id="hikashop_product_price_full"> 
    <span class="hikashop_product_discount">-10%</span>
    <span class="hikashop_product_price hikashop_product_price_0 hikashop_product_price_with_discount">51,34 €</span> 
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: ty for respond but i give u a example if var test it's change by the function that i created it take like a new var and add to it a % like it is a new number . ex test = 40 * x/100 + 40 and next time i call the function it test = total * x/100 + total i wnat to add just once  x/100 ( where x is the value from the select/option)

Comment: i need to take in var test initial price without change it from this select/option

Comment: I am somewhat confused by your comments and question.  I was using " I need to run just once to add % to the price" as the basis for this answer (run once). I would suggest you modify your question to show a "before" action, define the action (select change, click, whatever) and "AFTER" desired output action.

Comment: Question:

When I call the function price() it run the selection on this function and make the selection a int. How to make the selection static and the field select/option add to this static selection a percent just once per option.

I hope u understood.

Thank you.